# USB can not be mounted after formatting using `dd`

Tags: usb, mount

I had formatted this usb using dd. After that the computer is not mounting the usb. It is being detected as `lsusb` shows 

`samiron@samiron-Vostro-3558:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0781:558b SanDisk Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 064e:9209 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`
 
The command `fdisk -l`  gives:

```
samiron@samiron-Vostro-3558:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xdbe79634

Device     Boot     Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2046  449312767  449310722 214.3G  5 Extended
/dev/sda2       449312768 1953523711 1504210944 717.3G 83 Linux
/dev/sda5       432238592  449312767   17074176   8.1G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6            2048  432238591  432236544 206.1G 83 Linux

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.




Disk /dev/sdb: 58.4 GiB, 62746787840 bytes, 122552320 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x7425bd9a

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 122552319 122550272 58.4G 83 Linux
```

When I try to `mount` the following error shows:

`samiron@samiron-Vostro-3558:~$ mount /dev/sdb1
mount: /dev/sdb1: can't find in /etc/fstab.`

Any help to recover my usb will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a mount point:

```
mkdir /mnt/usb   ## Can be any directory
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/usb
```

You can setup a /etc/fstab entry to map your device to a mount point:

```
 /dev/sdb1   /mnt/usb                           ext4    defaults        1 2
```

With that entry you can use any of the following:

```
mount /dev/sdb1
mount /mnt/usb
mount -a   ## Mount everything in /etc/fsab
```

Comment: `mount /dev/sdb1 /media/usb-drive`  gives output : `mount: /media/usb-drive: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
`

Comment: Nevermind.  had to use `mkfs.ext4`. But got it.

Comment: You haven't given us the `dd` command you have used. Probably you can reformat the USB drive from Windows if you have a dual boot system as I suspect. You could have easily damaged the partition table on the usb drive with `dd` command as it is very low lovel ... Perhaps your `dd` format command is still in bash history?

Comment: Sure. The command I used was : `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=4k && sync
`

Comment: That had effectively overwritten partition table with zeros. Be warned that by using `mkfs.ext4` your usb drive's content won't be visible from WIndows in case you have a dual boot machine as I might have suspected.